# Hover link show table packed in divs and tables

Tags: html, css

Okay so I posted a question recently but ran into another problem.

I am trying to make a navigation menu where you hover over a link and a table is shown. Now the problem is that in my code the link is packed in two divs a table and the table I am trying to show is also inside this whole shebang. I made an example code to show you

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ThobiasN/FJksb/24/

Html code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a class='nav' href='#'>Hover me</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='dropdown'><p>Show me</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css code:

```
div table tr td.dropdown
{
    display:none;
}

div table tr td a.nav:hover + div table tr td.dropdown
{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're sticking with CSS and not using JavaScript? JavaScript would probably make this a lot easier.

However, if you want to do it purely with CSS, I think you will need to put your table inside the item over which the user has to hover. So instead of what you have in your question, use a structure like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class='nav' href='#'>Hover me
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='dropdown'><p>Show me</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would then need to style the `<a>` tag appropriately, putting the link text inside a `<span>` tag, if need be, so you can make it still look like a link.

The CSS to actually make the menu work will look something like this:

```
.nav:link .dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.nav:hover .dropdown, .nav:active .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

All this is telling the browser to do is make the table classed `dropdown` within an active or hovered `nav` link appear, and disappear when it is not active or hovered-on.

I created [an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/guypursey/yHeEK/), only bear in mind that I have used `<div>`s instead of `<table>`s, though you could put your `<table>` inside the `<div>` and I've used the classnames `menu` and `content` instead of `nav` and `dropdown` respectively.

Hope this helps. Good luck.